# Powershell: How do I Start/Stop a Service and all RequiredServices that are not already running when started?

Tags: powershell, recursion, service

How do I achieve the following in a couple of Powershell one-liners (one to start, one to stop)?

I want to start service **MyService** in Powershell and also start all other services that are *Required* by **MyService** (i.e. services on which **MyService** *Depends*) that are *not already started*. I want to then be able to stop **MyService** and all the services I originally started with **MyService**, but not all *other* services on which **MyService** depends that were *already started* when I started **MyService**.

To clarify:
If **MyService** *Requires* **Service1**, **Service2** and **Service3**, and **Service3** is *also* *Required* by **UnrelatedService** and is already running for **UnrelatedService** then I do not need/want to start **Service3** in order to start **MyService**. *Nor* do I want to stop **Service3** when I stop **MyService** because then **UnrelatedService** would fail. I *do* want to stop **Service1** and **Service2** when I stop **MyService** because they are *Required only* by **MyService**.

Secondly, I want to do this recursively, such that if there were other *RequiredServices* to **Service1** and **Service2** (recall **Service3** is already running, therefore so are the services on which **Service3** *Depends*) then I also want to start those other services on which **Service1** and **Service2** *Depend* and which are *not already started*.

Successful outcome would be that the list of *[all services that are running after]* I stop **MyService** *is the same as* the list of *[all services that were running before]* I started **MyService** and those on which it *Depends*.

My attempt

```
Get-Service MyService | 
   Select -expand RequiredServices | 
   Start-Service
```

> Start-Service : Service 'My Full Service Name (myservice)' cannot be
>   started due to the following error: Cannot start service MyService on
>   computer '.'. At line:1 char:57 + Get-Service MyService | Select
>   -expand RequiredServices | Start-Service + + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController)
>   [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Comment: And what's the question?  You may (re-)read the help topic [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Olaf "How do I do this in Powershell?" - sorry if that was not obvious. I am very new to Powershell so I am not sure how to even create an example, hence the detailed and precise description with the desired Outcome...

Comment: The next questions usually are: What have you tried so far? Please share your code and explain where you've got stuck or what does not work as expected. ;-)

Comment: `PS C:\Users\username> Get-Service MyService | Select -expand RequiredServices | Start-Service
Start-Service : Service 'My Full Service Name (myservice)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service MyService on computer 
'.'.
At line:1 char:57
+ Get-Service MyService | Select -expand RequiredServices | Start-Service
+
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand`

Comment: MyService is obviously a placeholder...

Comment: Are you running this as administrator? What service is failing to start?

Comment: @skeetastax - The above error message should be of RequiredServices rather than 'MyService'. Can you check once?  If you are not able to start a service it might be disabled. In that case, you need to run `Set-Service 'MyService' -StartupType manual`. Then please try to run the above to start the required services.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Good question but I'm pretty sure I am running as Admin.

Comment: Thanks @KarthickGanesan. I'll check if it is Disabled (it may have been for security, which is one of the reasons for wanting to be able to shut them down again - to minimize unnecessary service availability.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds you need a Foreach-Object statement here. IMO your pipeline just does not recognize the expanded RequiredServices as a 'service' object.

```
Get-Service MyService | select -ExpandProperty RequiredServices | % {Start-Service $_.Name}
```

Or more verbose:

```
Get-Service MyService | Select-Object -ExpandProperty RequiredServices | ForEach-Object {Start-Service $_.Name}
```

After this you would be starting your service:

```
Start-Service MyService
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the above doesn't look recursive to me and doesn't appear to provide a way to then stop all services that were started (but no other RequiredServices) after I am done.